# How to open .hxs Help files with DExplore.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I tried to open .hxs file with (with "hxs "extension with right click) with "dexplore.exe" from:

C:\Programme\Gemeinsame Dateien\Microsoft Shared\Help 9

but noting happens, I have Visual Studio 2008 SDK Version 1.0, and VS2008 installed on my system.

Any idea what to do in order to see .hxs Help files ?

Br,

Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Hxs files must be merged into the collection and then you can open it via dexplore.exe.

It is not .CHM so you cannot directly open it in dexplore.exe. But thirdparty viewers such as h2viewer exists,

http://www.helpware.net/mshelp2/h20.htm