# Is there API for offline MSDN documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, api, documentation, msdn

I want use offline msdn documentaton in my application.
Is there api for that ?

Check out similar question
[How to open .hxs Help files with DExplore.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677126/how-to-open-hxs-help-files-with-dexplore-exe)

Comment: What are you talking about? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) is an online developer site.

Comment: check out this similar question this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701193/download-windows-api-reference-msdn-for-offline-use

Comment: @BoltClock: ? MSDN has been available as an offline install for a while i thought (maybe it isn't anymore?).

Comment: @BoltClock, I think he means the MSDN library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [MS Help 2.x API](http://www.mshelpwiki.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Help2API)

### [MS Help Viewer 1.0 API](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/faq/api)

**[Microsoft Help 2.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2)** is a proprietary format for online help files, developed by Microsoft and first released in 2001 as a help system for Visual Studio .NET (2002) and MSDN Library.
It's the help engine used in Microsoft Visual Studio 2002/2003/2005/2008 and Office 2007.

Visual Studio 2010 uses a new help engine, **[Microsoft Help Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_Viewer)**

#### Tools

**[MS Help 3 Viewer](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/viewer)** replace the VS 2010 help viewer or run stand-alone.

**[Visual Studio 2010 Help Downloader](http://vshelpdownloader.codeplex.com/)** for downloading base Visual Studio 2010 MSDN package for offline first installation.

**[Package This](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/)** is a GUI tool written in C# for creating help files (.chm and .hxs) from the content obtained from the MSDN Library (MSHelp 2.0)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the API documentation is built on HelpPane which is built into current versions of Windows. The interaction with it is based on a COM interface and URL for topics etc.

To interact via your own SW with HelpPane add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\HelpPaneProxy.dll` to the project then you can use the HelpPane like this

```
HxHelpPane pHelpPane = new HxHelpPane(); 
pHelpPane.DisplayTask("mshelp://windows/?id=e725b43f-94e4-4410-98e7-cc87ab2739aa");
```

After installing MSDN locally you should be able to see which local URLs are in use...

Further references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728704%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728715%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757030.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728718%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728713%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I think this is obsolete

Comment: @diimdeep glad that you found what you were looking for... for others to profit from your findings the right way here on SO would be that you post your findings not inside your question but as an answer...

Comment: > Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: @diimdeep I didn't check on reputation for doing so...